# cloudinary.exceptions.Error: Empty file using Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, cloudinary

Im using cloudinary for upload file from my flask app.
I followed this basic sample code by pycloudinary for flask : https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/tree/master/samples/basic
but I still get the same error.

```
cloudinary.exceptions.Error 
cloudinary.exceptions.Error: Empty file
```

My file post request with multipart-form and key name "image".
Before this, I already successfully upload file to static folder.

What should I do ?

```py
def upload_files():
    upload_result = None
    file_to_upload = request.files['image']
    if file_to_upload:
        upload_result = upload(file_to_upload)
        return "Success!"
    else:
        return "Failed!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Should file_to_upload = request.files['image'] be
file_to_upload = request.files['file']?

request.files is a ImmutableMultiDict() that `file` is the key and not `image`.

Best,
Mo

Comment: Thanks for answering this, but I already tried that and the result is KeyError.